# Mysql: Order by rand just one time

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-order-by

I need to make an order by rand but i dont want it to change in every refresh i need just one random , is that make sense ?

Here is my code:

```
function findSimilarByTag($gid,$limit=5) {
  $gid=$this->quotesmart($gid);
  $limit=$this->quotesmart($limit); //yes, this is senseless

  $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
  $query ="SELECT count( a.cid ) , a.gid, b.* \r\n";
  $query.="FROM `#__yfl_game2cat` a \r\n";
  $query.="JOIN #__yfl_game b ON a.gid = b.id
        WHERE a.cid
        IN (
        SELECT cid
        FROM #__yfl_game2cat
        WHERE gid = '$gid'
        )
        AND a.gid != '$gid'
        GROUP BY a.gid
        ORDER BY rand()
        LIMIT ".$limit;

  $db->setQuery($query);
  $games=$db->loadObjectList();
  if($db->getErrorMsg()) $games=$db->getErrorMsg();
  return $games;
```

Comment: what in God's name is one random ?

Comment: He wants to reorganize the results, but somehow store this reorganization and not randomize on each view

Comment: If you only need *one random* then your limit has to be one always...unless the query only return one record....by default... :$

Comment: Sounds like you can use a cache (e.g. file or memory based cache).

Comment: Is this per user or do you want **all users** to see the same "once random" order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For all users to see the same random order**

If you want the same random order to be for everyone, just add another column into which you put a  randomly generated number and order by that column.

**Per user:**

If the results set would be the same (i.e. no other data changes) you could store the whole results set in session.

```
session_start();// top of all php files that need to use session

if (isset($_SESSION['findSimilarByTag'])) $rs=$_SESSION['findSimilarByTag'];
else $rs=$_SESSION['findSimilarByTag']=findSimilarByTag($gid);
// ... go ahead and use $rs
```

If other data from the results changes, or that results set would be a lot of data, you could store the unique IDs and use `ORDER BY FIELD(fieldname, 1,2,3...)` instead of `ORDER BY RAND()` if that session value exists

Comment: But wouldn't all users have their own copies of the cache? I mean, in the extreme case, if all the users are different people with just one visit each, then it would behave exactly like randomizing at each request.

Comment: OP didn't specify this was per entire site or per user. Have asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of randomising on SELECT, create a column for the random value, populate it on INSERT and ORDER BY that column when SELECTing.

That way your results will always be returned in that predefined "random" order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean, but I can tell you that you can manipulate `RAND()` with an integer parameter. like `RAND(10,15)` will create random number between 10 to 15. As for returning "One random" then, I would store `$rand = "ORDER by RAND()";` then set up a session and check with `isset()` to see if RAND has been set once before or not.